# Visual Studio navigate dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2017, shortcut

Ctrl + , to open navigate dialog doesn't work in VS 2017. Has this shortcut been removed completely or just changed? if changed, then what is it now?

Comment: Works for me. Did you install resharper or something that might override the default keybindings?

Comment: I did had resharper installed originally, but now its disabled and im pretty sure my free trial expired now.

Comment: Yeah, but it may override keybindings - I don't know that it would return them to the defaults.

Comment: Had to reset the keybindings Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> RESET. Thanks for the hint @DigiFriend

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your key bindings are all at their defaults - extensions (such as Resharper) can set them to something else.

You can reset them by following these menues:

```
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> RESET
```